# Ignore specific CSP error when using sentry

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, content-security-policy, sentry

I am using hash-based `script-src` CSP(v2), together with Sentry's `report-uri` in my site.

Recently I am getting lots of CSP violation report, specifically from latest version of Firefox (version 66 as of writing), creating lots of noise.

```
Recently Blocked 'script' from 'inline:'
```

Testing with a firefox installation on my own computer, I found out that many addons actually inject inline script into DOM, thus triggering CSP error.

It is possible to ignore/mitigate this problem via CSP rule, or can I ignore all these firefox entries somehow via sdk or dashboard settings?

Answer (score 3):

I received an answer from Sentry customer service:

"You can ignore these by going into your project's settings, then `Security Headers > CSP Instructions > 'Additional ignored sources'`, and paste in the `blocked_uri` value from the Event's CSP Report."

In this case the `blocked_uri` value would be `inline`. Note that it will ignore all `inline` report, not just from firefox, but this is good enough for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can allow `'unsafe-inline'` as a source, although doing so significantly weakens the security offered by CSP.  (If you need to use unsafe-inline, I believe you have to NOT use the hash, as the hash supersedes the 'inline' directive.)